# Empty response headers from Spring MockMvc with springSecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test

I write unit tests for my Spring MVC application.

This is my mockMvc initialization code:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMockFactory {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MockMvc getMockMvc() {
        return webAppContextSetup(wac)
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Everything works good, but when I add springSecurityFilterChain response headers are always empty (it's important cause I want to check Set-Cookie header).

I use this code to perform action:

```
resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/login")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .param("username", "sysadmin")
                .param("password", "password")
).andDo(print());
```

And this is the result of andDo(print()):

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 200
   Error message = null
         Headers = {}
    Content type = null
            Body = {"status":200}
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

The question is why are the response headers empty when I use springSecurityFilterChain with mockMvc? And how to read them?

Comment: I have same problem...Tried to test different combinations of filters/etc. with no luck.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add Spring security configuration to your `MockMvc` object.

Example:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).apply(springSecurity()).build();
```

The `springSecurity()` initializer is available in `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers` package. You can conveniently static import it.
Note that you need `org.springframework.security:spring-security-test` dependency (I was good with 4.0.1.RELEASE).

See an example [here](https://github.com/ferrarimarco/is-web-app/blob/master/src/test/java/info/ferrarimarco/uniroma2/is/BaseSpringMvcContextTest.java) (didactic project).

I didn't need to manually set a Spring Security filter chain.